# Accessing nested data in templates

Tags: templates, parse-order

I'm trying to use a template to parse through nested data, but some of the child data has the same variable names as the parent. In the example below I'd like to print a list of shows and then a list of the episodes for each show, but the id, title, & description are parsed and given the parent data.

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'LOST',
        'description' => 'Best. Show. Ever',
        'episodes' => array (
            array ( 
                'id' => 1001,
                'title' => 'Pilot',
                'description' => 'The one where the plane crashes.'
            ),
            array ( 
                'id' => 1002,
                'title' => 'Dr. Jack',
                'description' => 'Jack saves everyone.'
            )
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'Seinfeld',
        'description' => 'Funniest. Show. Ever',
        'episodes' => array (
            array ( 
                'id' => 2001,
                'title' => 'Pilot',
                'description' => 'The one where it wasn\'t funny yet.'
            ),
            array ( 
                'id' => 2002,
                'title' => 'Kramer',
                'description' => 'Kramer isn\'t that funny yet either.'
            )
        ),
    ),
);

$tags = '<h1>{title}</h1>
<p>{description}</p>
<h2>Episodes:</h2>
<ul>
{episodes}
<li><em>{id}: {title}</em> {description}</li>
{/episodes}
</ul>';

$output = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables( $tags, $data );

echo $output;
?>
```

This generates the output below:

```
<h1>LOST</h1>
<p>Best. Show. Ever</p>
<h2>Episodes:</h2>
<ul>

<li><em>1: LOST</em> Best. Show. Ever</li>

<li><em>1: LOST</em> Best. Show. Ever</li>

</ul><h1>Seinfeld</h1>
<p>Funniest. Show. Ever</p>
<h2>Episodes:</h2>
<ul>

<li><em>2: Seinfeld</em> Funniest. Show. Ever</li>

<li><em>2: Seinfeld</em> Funniest. Show. Ever</li>
```

How can I access the episode data? If the field names are different it works just fine, but this data is coming from a web service that is not easily changed.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using PHP to output your data?

I know you can attempt this with [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa), and a couple channels.

Comment: That was just for example sake. The data is coming back from a REST web service call using Phil Sturgeon's rest plugin. So all of that PHP is actually taking place inside the plugin, and then I'm accessing it via a "normal" template. The data isn't in EE, so channels & playa aren't an option.